# Powershell outputting info into text file but not into output pane

Tags: powershell

got a script here which I require the results that export into the text file to also show in the output pane at the bottom. Can anyone help please?

The results I've currently got is that it only shows the Make and model of the machine but not the others from Domain all the way to memory left in GB. I want it all to show on the output pane at the bottom and also to save in a text file which saves and opens straight away.

Please note: The file opens with the data in but the main issue is that it doesn't show in the output pane. Here is the script:

```powershell
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Setting Execution Policy to Remote Signed..." -ForegroundColor Yellow 
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
Write-Host "Your execution policy is set to:" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
Get-ExecutionPolicy
Start-Sleep -s 3
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Generating computer statistics..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host " "
Start-Sleep -s 2
function systemstats {
Write-Host "Manufacturer:" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
Write-Host "$($m.Manufacturer)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host "Model:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "$($m.Model)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host "Domain:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
$env:USERDOMAIN
Write-Host "Computer Name:" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
$env:COMPUTERNAME
Write-Host "Operating System & Location:" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).name
Write-Host "OS Architecture:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
if ((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select osarchitecture).osarchitecture -eq "64-bit")
{
    Write "64-bit OS"
}
else
{
    Write "32-bit OS"
}
Write-Host "OS Build:" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
(Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).version
Write-Host "Version:" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ReleaseID).ReleaseID
Write-Host "Current IP Address:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Ipconfig | Select-String IPv4
Write-Host "Calculating RAM installed in MB:" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
(systeminfo | Select-String 'Total Physical Memory:').ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim()
$m = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property * |
Select-Object -Property Manufacturer, Model)
Write-Host "Disk Space in GB:" -ForegroundColor Cyan
gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
}
$result=(systemstats)
$result | Out-File "C:\Users\brendan.hargate\Desktop\test.txt"
Invoke-Item "C:\Users\brendan.hargate\Desktop\test.txt"
```

Comment: You see only your local machine info because you are running this locally.
You have to connect to AD and get all the computer objects and then use a foreach loop to get the info for each computer object.

Comment: I know that I wasn't asking that. The point of the question is to see if anyone can provide help with why it's not showing in the output pane at the bottom aswell as being in a text document.

Comment: It is not showing because you are saving it in test.txt directly
before you do that, call $result first

Comment: It does already say $result if you look right at the bottom of the script.

Comment: But you are sending the output to the test.txt so nothing is showing in your powershell console. There is nothing to show after you have saved it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-5.1) instead of `Out-File`:

```
$result | Tee-Object -FilePath "C:\Users\brendan.hargate\Desktop\test.txt"
```

`Tee-Object` (inspired by [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command))), will duplicate the input stream - one copy is passed on down the pipeline (which in your case will end up in the command pane), the other is written to a variable or a file (like in the above example)

Comment: Thanks for that but now it doesn't show any of the write hosts

Answer (score 0):

Your `systemstats` function *in part* uses `Write-Host` which operates outside of PowerShell's (success) output stream.

`Write-Host` output cannot be captured (PSv4) / is by default not captured (PSv5+) in variables or output files. As the name suggests, **`Write-Host` writes to the host UI (the console), and is *not* meant to output *data*** - that's what `Write-Output` and its alias, `Write`, as well as *implicit* output (e.g., `$env:USERDOMAIN` by itself) are for.

A variable assignment such as `$result = ...` only captures (success) output-stream output, i.e., the implicit output and the output from the `Write` (a.k.a. `Write-Output`) command. By contrast, your `Write-Host` commands printed straight to the console.

Given that you sent `$result` to a file - without also printing it to the console - the net effect was that *only* the `Write-Host` output appeared in the console.

The solution therefore has two components:

- Modify your function to *only* use implicit output (`Write-Output` output) in order to produce data output.
- Then use `Tee-Object` to print to *both* the console (via the success output stream) *and* a file, as suggested in [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47535377/45375).

---

As an aside, in PSv5+, you *could* get away with the following (although it is ill-advised), based on the ability to capture `Write-Host` output - now a virtual alias of `Write-Information` - via the newly introduced output stream number `6`:

```
systemstats 6>&1 | # PSv5+: redirect the information stream to the (success) output stream.
  Tee-Object -FilePath "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop'))\text.txt"
```